# How to convert object to array but not array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
const foo = {
    A: {
        id: 1231,
        f1: "Asdasd",
        f2: [1, 2]    
    },
    B: {
        id: 2324,
        f1: "Asdasd",
        f2: [1, 2]    
    }
}

console.log(Object.entries(foo));
```

So this creates Array of arrays which first index of each array is key and second index of each array is value.

But is there a easier way to convert object to array of objects
something like this;

```js
const bar = [
  {
    "some key name": "A",
    ...rest of the object A
  },
  {
    "some key name": "B",
    ...rest of the object B
  }
]
```

Comment: Yes, why not try `{ "key": "A", ...foo.A }`?

Comment: this is also good idea too but it turns out that i don't even need to include key.

Comment: No that's right. You don't need the extra key property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could `map` over `Object.entries`

```js
const foo = {
    A: {
        id: 1231,
        f1: "Asdasd",
        f2: [1, 2]    
    },
    B: {
        id: 2324,
        f1: "Asdasd",
        f2: [1, 2]    
    }
}

var arr = Object.entries(foo)
    .map(entry => ({
        "some key name":entry[0], ...entry[1]
    }))

console.log(arr);
```

---

Original answer was using `values` and `reduce`, but I misunderstood the question

```js
var arr = Object.values(foo).reduce(function(res, v) {
    return res.concat(v);
}, []);
```

Comment: it turns out i don't actually need to include the key so this helped a lot thanks. I didn't know you could use the reduce function like this.

Comment: I misread the question and updated to match your "original" need